# Max / min values with MongoDB document

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, nosql

I am using Spring Data to access MongoDB database.
How can I retrieve max a document with max value in one of its fields, using MongoTemplate class.
Thanks!

Comment: are you able to get an answer on this? as i need the exactly same.

Comment: Hi. Explain, please, whad do you want to do, I will try to help you

Comment: Are you using repositories ?

Comment: Hi. I don't remember, after 3 years

Answer (score 1):

use a combination of sort and limit to emulate min and max:

> db.test.insert({a: 1})
>   db.test.insert({a: 2})
>   db.test.insert({a: 3})
>   db.test.find().sort({a: 1}).limit(1) 
>   db.test.find().sort({a: -1}).limit(1)
>   sort({a: 1}) is an ascending (minimum-first) sort on the a field, and then only return the first document, which will be the minimum value for that field.
>   sort({a: -1}) is an descending (maximum-first) sort on the a field, and then only return the first document, which will be the maximum value for that field.

Comment: This is command line commands, but I use Java+ Spring Data. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rinku's answer is correct but not Spring.  You can do this in spring-data-mongodb.  Mongo will optimize sort/limit combinations IF the sort field is indexed (or the @Id field).  Otherwise it is still pretty good because it will use a top-k algorithm and avoid the global sort ([mongodb sort doc)](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/).  This is from [Mkyong's example](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/spring-data-mongodb-get-last-modified-records-date-sorting/) but I do the sort first and set the limit to one second.

```
Query query = new Query();
query.with(new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "idField"));
query.limit(1);
MyObject maxObject = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, MyObject.class);
```