# Spring CRUD repository: is there findOneByMaxXYZColumn()?

Tags: spring-data

My requirement:

fetch ONE object (e.g RetainInfo ) from table RETAIN_INFO if VERSION column has max value

Does CRUD repository support for an interface method like

```
findOneByMaxRetVersionAndCountry("DEFAULT")
```

Equivalent db2 sql:

```
select RET_ID, max(ri.RET_VERSION) from RETAIN_INFO ri  where ri. COUNTRY='DEFAULT'  group by RET_ID  fetch first 1 rows only;
```

- This query selects an ID, but I would actually want the RetainInfo object corresponding the SINGLE row returned by the query.

I prefer to get that without using  custom query, i.e using findBy or some other method/interface supported by Spring CRUD.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Max / min values with MongoDB document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14425900/max-min-values-with-mongodb-document)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Spring Data doesn't provide an expression to select a max value. All supported query parts could be found in the Spring 1.2.0.RELEASE docs: [Appendix A. Namespace reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords) or [line 182 of org.springframework.data.repository.query.parser.Part](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/repository/query/parser/Part.java#L182).

Also feel free to create a feature request at [Spring's Jira page](http://jira.spring.io).

Answer (score 62):

You could use limiting in combination with sorting ([spring data reference:limit query results](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result)). Declare a method similar to the following in your CrudRepository interface :

```
RetainInfo findTopByCountryOrderByRetVersionDesc(String country);
```

Comment: This started being ludicrously expensive when run on a large table. I implemented it manually with a `select max(t.field) from Table t` JPQL query.

Comment: @MariusSchär: Of course your query is much cheaper, because it just searches a max value. The original answer was: find the whole entity by a max column value. Therefore you have to use a subquery: `select * from table a where a.column = (select max(b.column) from table b and b.country = a.country) and b.country = "xxx")`

Comment: @Bernad Kern, in this case would be better to create a native statement with subquery or to do it as you suggested in your Answer using findTop (or findFirts)?

Answer (score 24):

You can also use **findFirst** to get the first result. Before getting the result, make sure to use **Orderby** and then the ascending(**Asc**) or descending(**Desc**). As an example if you want to order by version and retrieve based on productName

```
RetainInfo findFirstByProductNameOrderByVersionDesc(String productName);
```

Comment: This throws 'org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException' exception - when there is more than 1 row in the table... for some reason.

I'm sorting by ID. Method name: findFirstByOrderByIdDesc

Comment: For me, that worked, did it like `findFirstByOrderByUpdatedOnDesc()`