# Spring data method name for getting rows having max column value

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

This is the dummy data in my dummy `temp` table:

[image]

Above, there is no data in `columna`, however that is just by accident. I want to get rows having

- no data in `columna`
- having `columnb` value matching input parameter value
- having `columnc` value be max numeric equivalent for that column. (That is `columnc` is of type `character varying(255)`, but I know there will be `integer`s in that cell. So I want only those rows which have the maximum integer equivalent value for the column, i.e. 1 in above data)

The query will look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM temp 
WHERE
    columnb = 'ia' 
    AND coalesce(columna, '') = '' 
    AND CAST(coalesce(columnc, '0') AS integer)
        =(
          SELECT MAX(CAST(coalesce(columnc, '0') AS integer)) 
          FROM temp
          WHERE
              columnb = 'ia' 
              AND coalesce(columna, '') = ''
         );
```

The output look like this:

[image]

**Q1.** Is it possible to have this done by Spring data JPA method name based queries? (Primarily I see this might not be possible as I came across [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801219/spring-crud-repository-is-there-findonebymaxxyzcolumn)). Say something like this:`findByColumnbAndColumnaIsNullAnd<Something for filtering on max value of columnc>(String columnaValue)`?

**Q2.** Is it possible to do Q1 if the `columnc` is of numeric type?

**Q3.** Is the native query (with `@Query` annotation) is the only way to do this in spring-data jpa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post you linked is 3 years old.

**Q1:** It's not. Your query is too complicated and `MAX`/`COALESCE` are [not supported](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods). You will have to write a JPQL query.

**Q2:** See Q1.

**Q3:** No, JPQL is possible (`@Query` with `native = false`).

NOTE: Another solution is to do a view (= native query) and an `@Immutable` entity.

Comment: In Q1, I was talking about the method name, not the native query.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. No, it's not possible.