# Get Max Value with Spring-JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I want do query to my table with spring-JPA (I can't use @Query) for get the max register

The query have any conditions:

Initially my query get register where version is "x" and Validated is 1 and the process is a list.

```
version: "1A" 
validated: 1 -> It is always 1.   
lista: ["process1","process2"] or with 3,4 process...

myRepo.findByIdVersionCierreAndAndValidatedAndIdProcessIn(version, 1, lista);
```

But In my database I can be two registers:

```
1º

version: "1A" 
validated: 1 
lista: ["process1","process2"]
Exec: 1

2º

version: "1A" 
validated: 0 
lista: ["process1","process2"]
Exec: 2
```

I need get the register with max Exec, because in my register 1º, validated is 1, **BUT** in my register 2, validated is 0 y con my old code, I get the register Exec1 - `"myRepo.findByIdVersionCierreAndAndValidatedAndIdProcessIn(version, 1, lista);"`

First I saw the post:
[Spring CRUD repository: is there findOneByMaxXYZColumn()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801219/spring-crud-repository-is-there-findonebymaxxyzcolumn)

So I modified my code:

```
 myRepo.findFirstfindByIdVersionCierreAndAndValidatedOrderbyIdExecDescAndIdProcessIn(version, 1, lista);
```

Err:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query method public abstract java.util.List es.repository.DataValidationRepository.findFirstfindByIdVersionCierreAndAndValidatedOrderbyIdExecDescAndIdProcessIn(java.lang.String,int,java.util.List)! No property orderbyIdExecDesc found for type int! Traversed path: TpValidaAuto.validated.
```

And

```
 myRepo.findFirstfindByIdVersionCierreAndAndValidatedAndIdProcessInOrderbyIdExecDesc(version, 1, lista);
```

however I get a error when I run the SpringBoot:

```
   Caused by: org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property inOrderbyIdExecDesc found for type String! Traversed path: TpValidaAuto.idProcess.
```

EDIT:

```
@Repository
public interface DataValidationRepository extends CrudRepository<TpValidaAuto, String> {
    List<TpValidaAuto> findByIdVersionCierreAndAndValidatedAndIdProcessIn(String version, int validated, List<String> process);
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MyTable")
@GETTER
@SETTER
public class TpValidaAuto {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID_FICHERO")
    @JsonProperty("file")
    private String idFile;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID_EJECUCION")
    @JsonProperty("exec")
    private int idExec;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "ID_PROCESO")
    @JsonProperty("process")
    private String idProcess;

    @Column(name = "ID_PERIODO")
    @JsonProperty("period")
    private String idPeriod;

    @Column(name = "FC_ULT_DATO")
    @JsonProperty("lastdatedata")
    private String lastDateData;

    @Column(name = "IND_INCLUIR_CIERRE")
    @JsonProperty("validated")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.BOOLEAN)
    private int validated;

    @Column(name = "ID_VERSION_CIERRE")
    @JsonProperty("lastdateclose")
    private String idVersionCierre;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "IND_DATOS_MODIF")
    @JsonProperty("modificated")
    private int modificated;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "FC_ALTA")
    @JsonProperty("createDate")
    private String createDate;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "USR_ALTA")
    @JsonProperty("createUser")
    private String createUser;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "FC_MODIFICACION")
    @JsonProperty("modificationDate")
    private String modificationDate;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "USR_MODIFICACION")
    @JsonProperty("modificationUser")
    private String modificationUser;

@JsonGetter("validated")
public boolean validated() {
    boolean result = true;

    if (this.validated == 0) {
        result = false;
    }

    return result;
}

@JsonSetter("validated")
public void validated(boolean validated) {
    if (validated) {
        this.validated = 1;
    } else {
        this.validated = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Include your entity with exact properties

Comment: oK I modified the post.

Comment: Why is it you cannot use `@Query`? If you can use a finder method yu can use an `@Query`.

Comment: Because, this app should be runs for BBDD relationals and BBDD not relationals

Comment: So this should work with relational databases as well as with non relational ones?

Comment: Exactly, the problem this build is that I have an "Array"