# Spring JPA finding max() primary key value in a table

Tags: sql, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have to limit the maximum primary key value for a table to 99 for my assignment. So I need to get the entry in the table with the highest primary key value, and then see if adding +1 to it will go above 99. Since Spring JPA repositories do not support the max() function, I have been trying to do this by using the keywords.

The table is extremely simple and only has an autoincremented int value, and another varchar field to store a name.

In simple sql the query would be:

```
SELECT max(primarykey_column) FROM table;
```

What I have been trying:

From this answer: [Spring CRUD repository: is there findOneByMaxXYZColumn()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801219/spring-crud-repository-is-there-findonebymaxxyzcolumn)

```
Item findTopByOrderByItemId();
```

This one returns the smallest value instead of the largest one, the problem is there is no findBottomByOrderByItemId. Im really lost at this point and it seems like such a simple small problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After orderByItemId use Desc it will work